# How to make an image with an anchor tag to be displayed in one line?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<td class="fmt-str-h">
<a href="#">
<img class="icon" src="img/preferences-system.png">
Tools</a>
</td>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
TD.fmt-str-h     { text-align: left; padding: 4px 8px 4px 12px; }
TD.fmt-str-h A   {color: #fff;}
A                { text-decoration: none;
                   color: #0071dd;
                   font-weight: normal; }
IMG.icon         { padding: 2px;
                   color: #FFF;
                   cursor: pointer;
                   vertical-align: middle; }
```

[This is the result of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmNsY.jpg)

So, I want to make the icon to be in one line with its anchor tag. I tried with "display:inline-block" on the TD and the Anchor but nothing happened.
Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to your `fmt-str-h A` class

```
TD.fmt-str-h A {  
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```